# How to represent a map data structure mathematically

Tags: type-theory, notation, mathematical-foundations

Wondering how to represent a map object such as the following mathematically:

```
var foo = {
  a: 10,
  b: 'bar',
  c: true
}
```

You could say that it was a function like this:

```
foo(x, y, z)
```

where $x$ is an integer, $y$ is a string, and $z$ is a boolean. But the question then is how to say the names of the keys `a, b, c`. Something like:

```
foo(label(x, a), label(y, b), label(z, c))
```

But then wondering about how type theory deals with this, so I' a bit confused. Wondering how computer science would model this data structure using mathematical notation. Maybe:

$$
\begin{align*}
foo = \left\{
  \begin{array}{r@{}l}
& a = x \\
& b = y \\
& c = z
  \end{array}
  \right\}
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to represent it.

The simplest way is probably as a mathematical function $f:S \to T$ where $S$ is the type of the keys and $T$ is the type of the values.  In other words, you can represent it as a function/map.  Here we have $f(\mathtt{a}) = 10$, etc. (so this is different from the idea you mentioned in the question).

Here are some more sophisticated ways to encode this in a type system:

If the keys `a`, `b`, `c`, are statically known and never dynamic, and that set is fixed in advance and never changes, this could be represented as simply a tuple or a [record type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_(computer_science)).

If the keys are static but you want to extend them, you could represent this as an [extensible row type](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/53998/755).  See also [In type systems, is there a name for SQL's way of cutting and combining record types into new types?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19134/755) and [Is there any difference between extensible records and dependent maps](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/59738/755) and [Encoding row types](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/11613/755).

If the keys are fully dynamic (their possible values aren't known at compile time), it needs to be represented as a function (i.e., map type).